# Grails JSON marshallers in domain class

Tags: json, grails

I know in grails i can define diferent JSON marshallers and asign names to them for different uses, which is very nice. However i end with a lot of code in the Bootstrap section and i end with two places where i need to tweak when domain classes changes.

Ithink thi is not good enough and i wonder if it might be possible to define JSON marshallers in the domain class itself.

Do you think would it be a good practice? ... can you provide suggestions on the best approach to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: It's entirely up to you how you want to manage your code. I typically create a MarshallerBootstrap.groovy just for Marshallers. Here is also another idea: http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap.groovy write this code:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(YourClass) { YourClass yourClass->
        Map result = [:]
        result['yourClass.property'] = yourClass.property
        def domain = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(YourClass)
        domain.persistentProperties.each { GrailsDomainClassProperty property, String propertyName = property.name ->
               result[propertyName] = yourClass[(propertyName)]     
        }           
        return result
    }
```

Code below add one property, you can name it how u want

```
 result['yourClass.property'] = yourClass.property
```

This code add all properties by it's name to map:

```
domain.persistentProperties.each { GrailsDomainClassProperty property, String propertyName = property.name ->
               result[propertyName] = yourClass[(propertyName)]     
        }
```

Comment: What is event in "event[propertyName"?

Comment: @Kachwahed yes, have had mistake. Should be yourClass[(propertyName)]

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/json-apis) for this purpose specifically. It allows you to use annotations in domain classes, like this:

```
import grails.plugins.jsonapis.JsonApi
class User {

    static hasMany = [
        pets: Pet
    ]

    @JsonApi
    String screenName

    @JsonApi('userSettings')
    String email

    @JsonApi(['userSettings', 'detailedInformation', 'social'])
    String twitterUsername

    @JsonApi(['detailedInformation', 'userSettings'])
    Set pets

    String neverGetsSerialized

    @JsonApi('detailedInformation')
    Integer getNumberOfTicklyAnimals() {
        pets.count { it.likesTickling }
    }
}
```

In your controller, you would then call `JSON.use('detailedInformation')` to activate a specific marshaller.

Comment: mmm ... looks nice to me! ... maybe the name can be improved but it looks interesting

Comment: » There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things. « ;)